# SQL: Using outer join in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, outer-join

I'm trying to learn how to use the OUTER JOIN function in SQL Server, so that the select query returns all values from two tables, even the unmatched ones.

Here are the two sample tables I'm using (Boys and Girls):

```
Boys:

Name    City
Andrew  Cape Town
Mike    Paphos
Simon   Amsterdam

Girls:

Name    City
Georgia Paphos
Megan   London
Eva     Amsterdam
Stephi  Cape Town
```

Here is the query I've written:

```
SELECT boys.name, boys.city, girls.name, girls.city
    FROM boys, girls
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN boys as men ON boys.city=girls.city;
```

I'm trying to return a table as follows:

```
boys.Name     boys.City        girls.name        girls.city    
Andrew        Cape Town        Stephi            Cape Town  
Mike          Paphos           Georgia           Paphos  
Simon         Amsterdam        Eva               Amsterdam  
NULL          NULL             Megan             London
```

A normal inner join ignores the last line because it doesn't have a matching boy city.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: The `FROM boys, girls` join syntax is the older syntax (the term escapes me, atm) and uses an implicit inner join which is part of the reason why you're not seeing the results you want.

Comment: Why on earth do you have a table for each gender?

Comment: Its just a nonsense table to illustrate my problem

Comment: `FROM boys, girls RIGHT OUTER JOIN boys` - huh? Also is it really the case that any one city (e.g. Cape Town) will only ever have at most one boy and at most one girl? What results do you expect if Cape Town has two girls and one boy>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN that goes both ways instead of a RIGHT OUTER JOIN;

```
SELECT boys.name boys_name, boys.city boys_city,
       girls.name girls_name, girls.city girls_city
FROM boys
FULL OUTER JOIN girls 
  ON boys.city=girls.city
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0057/4).

Your existing query joins boys twice, once with the old join syntax and once with a right join. Using full outer join, you only have to include each table once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on the two tables.

You can find more details [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx).

For example:

```
SELECT boys.name, boys.city, girls.name, girls.city
    FROM girls
    FULL OUTER JOIN boys ON boys.city=girls.city;
```